# With Swashbuckle how to handle date in querystring the same as in json

Tags: .net, query-string, swashbuckle

I try to handle DateOnly et TimeOnly with Swashbuckle.

Using a request with a JSON body works like expected. I wrote a json converter for `DateOny` and `TimeOnly`, named `JsonStringDateTimeOnlyConverter`.
It is injected with `options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringDateTimeOnlyConverter());`.

I wrote a simple controller with 2 actions, POST and GET, with a single parameter `DateOnly date`.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] DateOnly date)
    {
        return Ok(date);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] DateOnly date)
    {
        return Ok(date);
    }
}
```

The generated description with Swashbuckle looks like this :

```json
    "/api/Test": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
              }
            },
            "text/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
              }
            },
            "application/*+json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      },
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Year",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Month",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Day",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "DayOfWeek",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DayOfWeek"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "DayOfYear",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "DayNumber",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The POST part is fine but the GET part handles DateOnly as a complex object and I couldn't find how to change this behaviour.

Is there any way to add a converter like with JSON but for the querystring ?

I tried to create an `IOperationFilter` but parameters are already set and I get the `DateOnly`'s properties, not the `date` parameter with type `DateOnly`.

Thank you.